# Java , adding minutes to a Date , weird anomaly

Tags: java, date

With Java Version 1.5.0_06 on both Windows and Ubuntu Linux :

Whenever I add minutes to the date "2008/10/05 00:00:00" , it seems that an extra hour is wrongly added.

ie: adding 360 minutes to 2008/10/05 00:00:00 at midnight should arrive at 2008/10/05 06:00:00

But it is arriving at 2008/10/05 07:00:00

The totally perplexing thing is that this **ONLY** happens when the day is 2008/10/05, all other days that I try perform the minutes addition correctly.

Am I going crazy or is this a bug in Java ?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        String date = "2008/10/05 00:00:00";
        int minutesToAdd = 360;  // 6 hrs

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToAdd);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    } catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Answer (score 18):

There's a crossover to daylight savings on that day.

Are you in New Zealand? If so, that means your timezone files are out of date. Better go to the Java download site and download new ones; look for "JDK DST Timezone Update Tool".

Comment: Hehehe, yep! Anyway, my comment about New Zealand is this, as of last year daylight savings was moved from first Sunday of October to last Sunday of September. Since Java 5 has been around a while, the zone files may indeed need updating.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be daylight savings kicking in?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

From the Documentation:

*"Joda-Time has been created to radically change date and time handling in Java. The JDK classes Date and Calendar are very badly designed, have had numerous bugs and have odd performance effects."*

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work (you reported using Java 1.5 back in 2008, before the advent of java.time, but I hope that you aren’t anymore). java.time can be considered the successor of the Joda-Time library that Willi aus Rohr mentions in his answer.

Let’s first define a formatter for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
```

Now to parse your string and add 360 minutes:

```
    String date = "2008/10/05 00:00:00";
    int minutesToAdd = 360;  // 6 hrs
    
    ZonedDateTime originalTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, PARSER)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland"));
    ZonedDateTime newTime = originalTime.plusMinutes(minutesToAdd);
    
    System.out.println(newTime);
```

Output on my Java 11:

> 2008-10-05T06:00+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

6 hours have been correctly added. You notice that a `ZonedDateTime` also print its UTC offset, here +13:00, so should you have an out-of-date time zone database in your Java installation, you also have a chance of seeing that the offset was not as expected.

If you want to add whole hours, prefer the `plusHours` method over `plusMinutes`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.