# Why is the month changed to 50 after I added 10 minutes?

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I have this date object:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
Date d1 = df.parse(interviewList.get(37).getTime());
```

value of d1 is `Fri Jan 07 17:40:00 PKT 2011`

Now I am trying to add 10 minutes to the date above.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d1);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Value of `newTime` changes to `2011-50-07 17:50`
but it should be `07-01-2011 17:50`.

It adds minutes correctly but it also changes month, don't know why!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java , adding minutes to a Date , weird anomaly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285818/java-adding-minutes-to-a-date-weird-anomaly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add one month to current date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905416/how-do-i-add-one-month-to-current-date-in-java)

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I disagree about the suggested duplicates. This question is related to [SimpleDateFormat ignoring month when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat-ignoring-month-when-parsing), but not a duplicate of it. It might, or may not be considered a duplicate of the much later [When Using Date Picker In Android It is Picking the Wrong Date \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645226/when-using-date-picker-in-android-it-is-picking-the-wrong-date).

Comment: idk if someone told you but you're parsing minutes and month with the same format, month are read with caps "yyyy-MM-dd" and minutes are read with lower case "HH:mm:ss", since you're parsing month with lower case the Calendar is adding your minutes to your month.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The issue for you is that you are using `mm`. You should use `MM`. `MM` is for month and `mm` is for minutes. Try with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

Other approach:

It can be as simple as this (other option is to use [joda-time](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/JodaTime.pdf))

```
static final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS=60000;//millisecs

Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
long t= date.getTimeInMillis();
Date afterAddingTenMins=new Date(t + (10 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
```

Comment: thanks , i tried this , date is coming correctly , but when i try to change it as string , it gives me the same wrong result     String newTime= df.format(afterAddingTenMins);   it gives me  2011-50-07 17:50  ,  I have to convert it in String, any suggestion

Comment: @junaidp you used the latter bit of code, but ignored the former part of the solution?

Comment: The error — using lower case `mm` instead of upper case `MM` — probably also means that the parsed date, Fri Jan 07 17:40:00 PKT 2011, is incorrect. The `SimpleDateFormat` does not pick up the month from the original string and defaults month to January.

Answer (score 63):

you can use DateUtils class in org.apache.commons.lang3.time package

```
int addMinuteTime = 5;
Date targetTime = new Date(); //now
targetTime = DateUtils.addMinutes(targetTime, addMinuteTime); //add minute
```

Comment: For folks dealing with older version of DateUtils, its present in package -> `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils`

Answer (score 33):

Convenience method for implementing @Pangea's answer:

```
/*
*  Convenience method to add a specified number of minutes to a Date object
*  From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043981/how-to-add-minutes-to-my-date
*  @param  minutes  The number of minutes to add
*  @param  beforeTime  The time that will have minutes added to it
*  @return  A date object with the specified number of minutes added to it 
*/
private static Date addMinutesToDate(int minutes, Date beforeTime){
    final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = 60000;//millisecs

    long curTimeInMs = beforeTime.getTime();
    Date afterAddingMins = new Date(curTimeInMs + (minutes * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
    return afterAddingMins;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

In order to avoid any dependency you can use java.util.Calendar as follow:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    Date teenMinutesFromNow = now.getTime();
```

In Java 8 we have new API:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plus(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
    Date tmfn = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Answer (score 19):

This is incorrectly specified:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
```

You're using minutes instead of month (MM)

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2016-01-23 12:34".replace( " " , "T" )
)
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Karachi" ) )
.plusMinutes( 10 )
```

## java.time

Use the excellent java.time classes for date-time work. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

### ISO 8601

The java.time classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default for parsing/generating strings of date-time values. To make your input string comply, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-01-23 12:34" ;
String inputModified = input.replace( " " , "T" );
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Parse your input string as a `LocalDateTime` as it lacks any info about time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( inputModified );
```

Add ten minutes.

```
LocalDateTime ldtLater = ldt.plusMinutes( 10 );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:34
>
> ldtLater.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:44

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/vMnyUo).

That `LocalDateTime` has no time zone, so it does *not* represent a point on the timeline. Apply a time zone to translate to an actual moment. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`, or [`Asia/Karachi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Karachi). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `PKT` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you know the intended time zone for this value, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Karachi" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:44+05:00[Asia/Karachi]

### Anomalies

Think about whether to add those ten minutes before or after adding a time zone. You may get a very different result because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) that shift the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

Whether you should add the 10 minutes before or after adding the zone depends on the meaning of your business scenario and rules.

Tip: When you intend a specific moment on the timeline, **always keep the time zone information**. Do not lose that info, as done with your input data. Is the value `12:34` meant to be noon in Pakistan or noon in France or noon in Québec? If you meant noon in Pakistan, say so by including at least the offset-from-UTC (`+05:00`), and better still, the name of the time zone (`Asia/Karachi`).

### `Instant`

If you want the same moment as seen through the lens of [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/coordinated_Universal_Time), extract an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

### Convert

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes whenever possible. But if you must, you can convert. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

There's an error in the pattern of your SimpleDateFormat. it should be

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 4):

use this format,

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

mm for minutes and MM for mounth

Answer (score 2):

Once you have you date parsed, I use this utility function to add hours, minutes or seconds:

```
public class DateTimeUtils {
    private static final long ONE_HOUR_IN_MS = 3600000;
    private static final long ONE_MIN_IN_MS = 60000;
    private static final long ONE_SEC_IN_MS = 1000;

    public static Date sumTimeToDate(Date date, int hours, int mins, int secs) {
        long hoursToAddInMs = hours * ONE_HOUR_IN_MS;
        long minsToAddInMs = mins * ONE_MIN_IN_MS;
        long secsToAddInMs = secs * ONE_SEC_IN_MS;
        return new Date(date.getTime() + hoursToAddInMs + minsToAddInMs + secsToAddInMs);
    }
}
```

Be careful when adding long periods of time, 1 day is not always 24 hours (daylight savings-type adjustments, leap seconds and so on), [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is recommended for that.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done without the constants (like 3600000 ms is 1h)

```
public static Date addMinutesToDate(Date date, int minutes) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

public static Date addHoursToDate(Date date, int hours) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

example of usage:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
System.out.println(addMinutesToDate(new Date(), 5));

Tue May 26 16:16:14 CEST 2020
Tue May 26 16:21:14 CEST 2020
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes, as of the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

Work for me DateUtils

```
//import
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils
```

...

```
        //Added and removed minutes to increase current range dates
        Date horaInicialCorteEspecial = DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(corteEspecial.horaInicial.getTime()),-1)
        Date horaFinalCorteEspecial = DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(corteEspecial.horaFinal.getTime()),1)
```

Comment: How does this Answer improve on the [one from last year posted by alireza alallah](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524459/642706)? Also, the Question referred to minutes, not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For android developers, here's a kotlin implementation using an extension of @jeznag's answer

```
 fun Date.addMinutesToDate(minutes: Int): Date {
    val minuteMillis: Long = 60000 //millisecs
    val curTimeInMs: Long = this.time
    val result = Date(curTimeInMs + minutes * minuteMillis)
    this.time = result.time
    return this
}
```

an unit test to check functionality works as expected

```
@Test
fun `test minutes are added to date`() {
    //given
    val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm").parse("29-04-2021 23:00")
    //when
    date?.addMinutesToDate(45)
    //then
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = date
    assertEquals(29, calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH])
    assertEquals(23, calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY])
    assertEquals(45, calendar[Calendar.MINUTE])
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just for anybody who is interested. I was working on an iOS project that required  similar functionality so I ended porting the answer by @jeznag to swift

```
private func addMinutesToDate(minutes: Int, beforeDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    var SIXTY_SECONDS = 60

    var m = (Double) (minutes * SIXTY_SECONDS)
    var c =  beforeDate.timeIntervalSince1970  + m
    var newDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: c)

    return newDate
}
```

Comment: Date from Swift had already similar build-in function, for example Date(timeInterval: , since: )